# How to use/start testnet with Ethereum

Tags: testnets, windows

I'm new to Ethereum and try to configure the initial test network.
I have installed geth and I believe that it has been synced (geth folder current size: 48.7 GB) 
There are three folders in appdata:
[image]

How can I know which network is synchronized fully and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to install mist.

Run geth, for instance

> > geth -rinkeby (or your preferred network)

Then start mist. It will show you the synchronization process in a user-friendly way.